# Chrome Web App Not Working As It Should

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have only very recently got into coding. In fact, yesterday. Right now I am trying to code a web app that, when pressed, displays a few buttons that when clicked play songs. However when I try to click on the buttons, it just does nothing. I believe it has something to do with chrome not allowing in-line java script, but I'm not 100% sure.

Here is my code

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var song = new Audio();
song.src = "SoundsOfSilence.mp3";

var song2 = new Audio();
song2.src = "ChildrenPlaying.mp3";
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    <a href="#" onclick="song.play()">Sounds Of Silence</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="song2.play()">Children Playing</a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the audio attribute tags. 
Such as:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="SoundofSilence.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="ChildrenPlaying.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: That somewhat works, however it only plays one song, and it doesnt have any buttons. I'm wanting something that is a list of some songs, and plays them when they are clicked. 

It's almost what i want but not quite. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I just messed around for little bit changing around some stuff. And it somewhat worked. Thanks man!